# Hibernate Search - recreate index if existing data was not indexed before

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I have an existing project that has a lot of data in DB. I am adding Hibernate Search to the project.
Since I want existing data to be indexed, I want to start indexing it on startup of my service via

```
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait()
```

But I want to do it only once (when existing data was not indexed) since all the later data changes will be synced.

So my question is: does Hibernate Search have any method to check if there are already created indexes for entities or not? I need it to understand if I have to rebuild all the indexes (on the first startup) or not (when my app started after upgrade, for example, and I don't have to purge all indexes and create them again) to avoid long startup every time I restart the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be safely and reliably detected by Hibernate Search, so we intentionally left this out.

It's best you add a method to trigger it yourself, so that you can control it explicitly; the MassIndexer can also be invoked easily via JMX.

I normally add a "rebuild indexes" button in my "admin" control panel view; that's always going to be useful ;-)